# How to remove media by filename?

Tags: uploads, media

For some reasons, when I´m doing an import of data to make posts and medias, I can have :

1. Some media not attached but with an image
2. Some files still saved in uploads folder but not visible in Library
3. Some media not attached but without image

The common point is the filename so,

how can I add in my php script to remove media/files by filename like :

1. If there is a media with this filename, remove it with the file if exists
2. If there is no media but the file is physically in the uploads directory, remove the file

Comment: I´m using `wp_delete_attachment` and I made a function compatible with wpml BUT to use this functions you should have the attachment id, for some cases I don´t have it, my question is more to do that thanks the filename and to remove phisically the file if there is no media. Of course, I searched for the web before.

Comment: I read your question again and it's quite clear in the title what you're asking so I deleted my comment as it wasn't appropriate.